# Is there any way to erase very thin lines in blender 2d?

Tags: 2d

I note that when I make very thin lines in blender 2d they become almost unerasable by the eraser tool. I have tried point and stroke erase they dont erase it immediately.

Comment: could you do that in Edit Mode? or just zoom in?

Answer (score 0):

Select an erase brush of type Soft/Hard.
Adjust brush settings.
Click and hold LMB or use the Pen tip to delete strokes on the viewport.

Comment: Didn't work >:/